# Auto scroll in chat app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a live chat, but I'm having trouble with having it automatically scroll down when there is a new message.

My Div is as followed:

```
<div id = "serverChat" style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;"></div>
```

and I tried using jquery like this:

```
var $chat = $('#serverChat');`
$chat.animate({scrollTop: $chat.get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

I'm not quite sure how to get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the ` after $('#serverChat'); also in your code?

Comment: I'd suggest searching for scroll-glue or sticky scroll implementations that may fit your needs. Implementing such things yourself might be a good exercise, but its reinventing the wheel. For example (https://plugins.jquery.com/scrollGlue/)

Comment: Is this jquery you have inside a message receive function? or on a change event?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the scrollHeight like this:

`document.getElementById('id').scrollHeight`

After that just pass it to your animation.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function(){
 var sh = document.getElementById('serverChat').scrollHeight;
 $("#serverChat").animate({ scrollTop: sh }, 600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="serverChat" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px;">
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
 s<br>
  s<br>
 s<br>
  s<br>
 s<br>
  s<br>
 s<br>
</div>
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method for scrolling to the end of block:

```
function scrollToEnd(block, duration) {
    // if block not passed scroll to end of page
    block = block || $("html, body");
    duration = duration || 2000;

    // you can pass also block's jQuery selector instead of jQuery object
    if(typeof block === 'string') {
        block = $(block);
    }

    // if exists at list one block
    if (block.length) {
        block.animate({
            scrollTop: block.get(0).scrollHeight
        }, duration);
    }
}
```

You need to call this method after putting new message to chat block:

```
scrollToEnd('#serverChat');
```

You can also use this method for scrolling down any other block or whole page.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gra8d6y/)**

```js
function scrollToEnd(block, duration) {
  // if block not passed scroll to end of page
  block = block || $("html, body");
    duration = duration || 2000;
    
    // you can pass also block's jQuery selector instead of jQuery object
  if(typeof block === 'string') {
        block = $(block);
    }
    // if exists at list one block
    if (block.length) {
      block.animate({
          scrollTop: block.get(0).scrollHeight
      }, duration);
    }
}


scrollToEnd('#serverChat');
scrollToEnd('#otherBlock', 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "serverChat" style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;">
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>
<p>Message</p>
<p style="float:right;">Answer</p>

</div>

<div id = "otherBlock" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px;">
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>

</div>
```